# Customize default Android honeycomb ActionMode appearance

Tags: android, selection, android-3.0-honeycomb, customization

I'm looking to change (within my application) the default appearance of the ActionMode popup.  My UI requirements call for a different appearance for text highlighting than the default green look so I'm trying to find out if it is somehow customizable or if I'm stuck with the defaults.  I think that creating my own action mode is the road I want to be taking, but I haven't been able to find any examples of anyone doing this.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there is no exposed API for actionMode customization in Honeycomb.  The feature is now available for Ice Cream Sandwich, but for honeycomb, you have to [hack your way through](http://blog.wu-man.com/2011/12/actionbar-api-provided-by-google-on.html) with some non exposed API.